# Message handler not working in WKWebView in iOS 9

Tags: javascript, swift, ios9, wkwebview

I've created an app that uses WKWebView to display an HTML page. I have embedded a button that calls a javascript function to post a message to my code. This works perfectly on iOS 12, but when I debug for iOS 9 it doesn't work at all. The message handler doesn't get called.

I've tried a couple of different ways to make this work for iOS 9 but it seems that nothing is working.

This is my swift code:

```
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let content = WKUserContentController()

content.add(self, name: "callback")
config.userContentController = content

page = WKWebView(frame: self.WKBaseView.bounds, configuration: config)
```

This is how i handle the message:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        dump(message.body)

}
```

This is what I call from the JS:

```
try {
      webkit.messageHandlers.callback.postMessage("test");
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('Can not reach app');
    }
```

Since this works perfectly on iOS 12, is this a bug in iOS 9 or is there some other way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Did you set the delegate?

Comment: I've set the flowing delegates: ```page.navigationDelegate = self
        page.uiDelegate = self
        page.scrollView.delegate = self```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. Turns out that it was a JavaScript error. Apparently iOS < 12 doesn't support "let" when declaring variables.